# Count the total elements of a path in Matlab

Tags: matlab, path, iteration

I'm working with a path with a lot of images and I need to make a for function to iterate all of them, and do stuff with each image. I made this funcion for this, but I miss one little detail:

```
myfiles = dir(fullfile('./mypath','*.png')); # path
for i=0:TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_IMAGES_OF_THE_PATHS
   im = imread(['./mypath/', myfiles(i).name,'']); # im = current image
   do stuff...
```

So, what can I put on that TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_IMAGES_OF_THE_PATHS?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need the number of files for `TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS`. `dir` returns a struct and you can get the number of elements using `length` or `numel`. So your `for` loop would read like:

```
for i=1:length(myfiles)
    ...
end
```

Comment: Additionally, it may be a good idea to add a `if ~myfiles(i).isdir` statement to skip the directories.

Comment: @Jonas He's using `dir` only to find `*.png` files... So unless he has also named directories with a `.png` extension, it shouldn't be necessary. But in general, yes, that's a good addition.

Comment: @yoda: to be more exact, DIR returns an array of structures